# How to hide the content inside body in html5?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have very long content in my page. Also my menu header is transparent with text over it. So, if i scroll the page, the whole content should be hidden behind the menu header. The content should not be seen through this header. My menu header should be transparent.
 How to do this?

> ```
> //code   
>  .navbar-fixed-top{
>     background-color:yellow;   
>     height:60px;
>     text-align:center;
>     font-size:40px;
>     opacity:0.7;
> }
>
> .content{
>     margin-top:65px;    
> }
> ```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/madhu72kumar/S8bS4/3/)

Comment: Then remove the transparancy from your header?

Comment: i can't remove opacity coz in my real project there is colorful image in the background.

Comment: You mean, in stead of yellow you have a background image? Why can't you remove the transparancy then? (or is the image itself transparent?)

Comment: transparent means -  allowing light to pass through so that objects behind can be distinctly seen.

Comment: @prash : i know wat is transparency. in my real project whole page is with a colorful background. So when i scroll, the whole body is scrolled along with the scrollbar and it should not be visible behind menu header which has opacity applied.

Comment: What should not be visible? The background image or the text?

Comment: @DimitriM text should not be visible

Comment: The answer would be to make your `.content` div fixed. When something is fixed, it is fixed on the screen, that means it cannot be scrolled (so the  .content` will never get behind the header. Here's a more detailed answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21830064/1915448

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to make the content container `fixed`. When it's fixed, the element itself cannot be scrolled (because it's fixed on the window). Then you can define the offset using the CSS `top` and `bottom` attributes.

The CSS would become something like this:

```css
.content {
    /** Absolute offset from the top */
    top: 65px; 
    /** Makes sure the content element itself cannot be scrolled (that way it can't get behind the header) */
    position: fixed;
    /** Offset from the bottom of the screen */
    bottom: 0;
    /** Show a scrollbar when there's a lot of content */
    overflow: auto;
}
```

I also updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8bS4/10/).

---

## Update

Based upon your comment I can tell you that it's actually impossible to do that only with CSS. The reason for this is that you should see these DOM nodes as layers. What you want is that a part of the layer becomes invisible (the text) while the other part (the background) isn't, but you can only say that you want to do the entire set (background + text) or none.

The only way to do this is by using JavaScript. You could emulate the scroll behavior by updating the `background-position` attribute of the `body`. For example by doing:

```js
$(".content").scroll(function() {
    $("body").css("background-position", "0 -" + $(this).scrollTop() + "px");
});
```

What this actually does is that when the `.content` is scrolled, the amount of pixels that is scrolled is also used to move the background, keeping them "synchronous".

I also updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8bS4/12/) to demonstrate this.

---

## Update 2

According to the comments you want to put the scrollbar over the entire page, so let me say this once again: DOM nodes are layers, if you want the scrollbar over the entire page, then the text is also over the entire page. There's no other way around it (it's common sense).

If you really want the scrollbar over the entire page and don't see the text, then it's quite simple: remove the transparency of the header. If you want the piece of background behind it, then you will have to put a `<div>` behind the header and with JavaScript move the background position (only on the piece behind the header). That new `<div>` would have no transparency and should be above the text layer. That means the header will not be entirely transparent so the text won't be visible.

But really, you should consider if you actually want to do this. It's a lot of work + code just for a small piece of UI behavior. I don't think it's a good practice to put all that JavaScript there for just that. I don't even think it's a good UI practice to do what you want, but if you really want it, well, I just told you how to do it, but here it also stops. I'm not going to write that piece of code for you, you have a base to start of so now you can continue.

Comment: That's impossible. You should see these DOM nodes as layers. You cannot say that a part of the layer should be visible (the background) and another part (the text) should not be visible.

Comment: Well, it's impossible with CSS only. I updated my answer to show you how you could do it with JavaScript (jQuery).

Comment: In ur JSFIDDLE, this is working without JS also. Is it possible to make the scrollbar applied to whole page ? and text hidden behind menu header.

Comment: Are you even listening to what I say? Like I said before, the DOM nodes are layers, if the scrollbar is applied to the whole page, then the text is **also** applied to the **whole page**, which means the text will get behind the header. What you're asking is impossible to do, like I already said before.

Comment: And no it is **not working without JS**. If you disable JavaScript in my second fiddle, then the background won't scroll, just like the first fiddle.

Comment: Well, it's not entirely impossible (nothing is), but it means a lot of extra effort. I've updated my answer with how you could achieve this, but I won't help you with that, the reason for that is also in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

remove the property `opacity` or make `opacity:1;`

Answer (score 2):

You have to set overflow and maximum height to your `.content` class  (no need to remove opacity )

```
.content{
     margin-top:60px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    max-height:400px; // your choice 
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/prash/S8bS4/4/

Comment: this is the answer i need. thank u. but i don't need two scrollbars for this. Is it possible to make single scrollbar for whole page?

Answer (score 1):

Update the css like below

```
//code
.navbar-fixed-top{
    background-color:yellow;   
    height:60px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:40px;
    }

.content{
    margin-top:65px;    
}
```

i have already updated here and it is working here.

[updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8bS4/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove Opacity:

```
.navbar-fixed-top{
    background-color:yellow;   
    height:60px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:40px;
    /*opacity:0.7;*/
}
```

Comment: i can't remove opacity coz in my real project there is colorful image in the background.

Answer (score 1):

> i can't remove opacity coz in my real project there is colorful image in the background

If your background image itself is transparent, you can specify a `background-color` alongside your image so that your element still has a solid background underneath:

```css
.navbar-fixed-top {
    background-color: #fff; // White
    background-image: url(...);
}
```

Or simply:

```css
.navbar-fixed-top {
    background: #fff url(...);
}
```

Comment: pls chk the question now.